# How to change color of 3D model with three.js without loosing the details of the model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I'm new to JavaScript and three.js and I'm trying to change the color of my 3D model. After reading the documentation, I added this line:`var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0xffff00} );` This changes my model to yellow from the default(white). However, I loose all the details in my model.

This is my code, please let me know what could I do about this. Cheers.

```
        var models = [
          {
            name: 'Bear',
            load: function(model) {
              stlLoader.load(
                '{{ url_for('static', filename='bear.stl') }}',
                function(geometry) {
                  // Regenerate normals because they aren't loaded properly.
                  geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                  geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                  // Load the model and build mesh.
                  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0xffff00} );
                  model.model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                  // Rotate, scale, and move so the bear is facing out the screen.
                  model.model.rotation.x = -90 * (Math.PI / 180.0);
                  model.model.scale.set(0.15, 0.15, 0.15);
                  model.model.position.y = -4;
                }
```

Comment: Try to use `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()` (any material that can be affected by light)

Comment: And when you use such materials, don't forget to add light source(s) to your scene.

Comment: Changing it to ``THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`` gives me exactly what I needed, thank you .

Comment: You're welcome :) Take a look at this example for reference: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html